# ListView not going below the buttons in linear layout

Tags: android, listview, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to get this layout

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lTHs.png

But for some reason the ListView keeps getting put to the side of the 3rd button and thus off the screen

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:weightSum="1.0">

<Button
    android:layout_weight=".33"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add"
    android:onClick="addPerson"
    android:id="@+id/add" />


<Button
    android:layout_weight=".33"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Edit"
    android:id="@+id/edit" />

<Button
    android:layout_weight=".33"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Delete"
    android:id="@+id/delete" />
```

Comment: Put your complete layout definitions, where is your ListView defined? you should consider adding android:orientation="horizontal" in your LinearLayout anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define two LinearLayouts, one with vertical orientation (for 3 buttons and the listview) and another with horizontal (for buttons) :

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:weightSum="1.0"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_weight=".33"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add"
        android:onClick="addPerson"
        android:id="@+id/add" />


    <Button
        android:layout_weight=".33"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Edit"
        android:id="@+id/edit" />

    <Button
        android:layout_weight=".33"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:id="@+id/delete" />
</LinearLayout>
<ListView
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   etc...etc
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use layout_weight so it can go down for as long as it can:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:weightSum="1.0"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".33"
        android:onClick="addPerson"
        android:text="Add" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/edit"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".33"
        android:text="Edit" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".33"
        android:text="Delete" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</LinearLayout>
```